# Why are my Bootstrap columns stacked instead of side by side?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, razor, printing

It is simple div container, div row, div col-md-9, div col-md-3.
This code has worked for the last 8 years or more and all of a sudden it doesn't.

It is the top part of a Final Approval letter in Razor that normally fits in an envelope window and has a logo and address of the sender on the right.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row" style="border: solid 4px blue;">
        <div class="col-md-9" style="border:solid 2px red;">
            <br /><br />
            <br /><br />
            <p>
                @DateTime.Today.ToString("MMMM dd, yyyy")<br />
                <br /><br /><br />
                @Model.Courses.CurrentContactName<br />
                @Model.Courses.ContactBizName<br />
                @Model.Courses.ContactAddress<br />
                @Model.Courses.ContactCity,  @Model.Courses.ContactState @Model.Courses.ContactZip<br />
            </p>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-3" style="border:solid 2px green;">
            <img src="~/images/oesac_white_2.25.jpg" />
            <br />
            <p style="font-size: 1.3rem;">
                OESAC CEU Committee<br />
                P. O. Box 577 <br />
                Canby, OR 97013-0577 <br />
                Phone: 503/698-6486 <br />
                Email: info@oesac.org <br />
                http://www.oesac.org

            </p>
        </div>

    </div> @*ROW*@
```

**Here is the webpage that gets created. It has a "Print" button which has JavaScript `onclick="window.print();` behind it. (I set the column's border colors to red and green for testing)**

[image: Webpage showing Final Approval letter correctly formatted, ready for printing]

**Here is the Printed Version, which I use a screenprint of the Print Preview in Chrome to demonstrate. (actual printed page does the same).**

[image: Here is Print Preview and Printed version with stacked columns.]

Please help me explain this problem if I haven't explained it correctly.
The bootstrap columns are designed to place the receiver's address in the middle of an envelope window, which works, but the Logo/Address of sender gets stacked below.

Comment: Protip: Don't use line breaks for spacing. That's not their purpose. Use margin or padding--Bootstrap provides many helpful classes for that. Please tag your Bootstrap version.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I got this to work:
I changed "<div class="col-md-9""
to "div class="col-sm-9""

and the right column I did the same:
"<div class="col-sm-9"
to "<div class = "col-sm-3"

Not sure why, because this page was printing correctly for the last 8 years.

Comment: Please format your code properly. The editor makes it quite easy.